# Writing,reading and deleting objects into file in java

Tags: java, object, file-io, objectinputstream

I want write list of objects into file, and then reading it one by one, and deleting respectively.
Writing and reading functions are below. For one by one reading,first I read all, then pop first, and other write to file again. it very ineffective and takes long time. So, what should I do to get better perfomance? Or maybe, there are  other variant to solve this problem

```
  public void writeToDisk(String filePath,TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> obj){
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        o.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> readFromDisk(String filePath){
    TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> invertIndexMap = null;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream f;
    try {
        f = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
        invertIndexMap = (TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>) s.readObject();
        s.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return invertIndexMap;
}
```

Comment: If you need random access you could put each object into its own file. Or use some kind of key-value store or embedded database system (like H2DB).

Comment: Is the TreeMap<...> one of your objects ? Or does it already define your full collection of objects ? In the first case I would recomment not to open the file every time you try to access it. If not then it depends on the size of your TreeMap.

Comment: You're not closing the `ObjectOutputStream` in this code.

Comment: @EJP Not nice, but shouldn't close on destruction ?

Comment: @EJP sorry, my error. I have already fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @Oncaphillis It's sorted Map of invert index, where key is word, and value is Arraylist of document ID where this word found. If this info can help,I trying to implement [SPIMI algo](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/single-pass-in-memory-indexing-1.html).